# CKEditor pop up is not working when the CKEditor is in a Dialogue Box

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 3.6.1 in my GWT project.

In a popped up Dialogue window , I have a CKEditor.

Here When I'm clicking Image upload or other tools from CKEditor toolbar, pop ups are successfully coming.

But I could not click or edit anything within the pop ups, even can't close the pop ups.

I used the CKEditor in a testing application where I used the CKEditor in normal widget, not in a Dialogue. There the CKEditor pop ups were worked fine.

Why the CKEditor pop ups are not working when they come over a Dialogue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, in my case ckeditor is in bootstrap modal.